# python function returns true when it should return false

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function to check whether a string is palindrome or not, but every string is showing as palindrome

```
def is_palindrome(input_string):    
    x=0
    reverse_string = ""
    while x<len(input_string):
        reverse_string+=input_string[x]
        x=x+1    
    if input_string == reverse_string:
        return True
    else:
        return False
    


print(is_palindrome("abc")) # Should be False but it return True
```

Comment: How is it you think the string is being reversed?

Comment: Your `reverse_string` is not reversed. I would advise to do some rudimentary debugging yourself before asking questions here.

Comment: your `x` should start at `len(input_string)-1` and decrease towards 0. But why you are not just doing `return input_string == input_string[::-1]`?

Comment: Here: you are using input_string[x] but you need to be adding input_string[-x] because otherwise you are getting the same string. You aren't actually reversing it. This solves your problem, not band-aiding it. (Note you might need to change some indices).

Comment: if you use a print statement to print the reverse_string in the while loop, it will become apparent why it is always returning true.

Comment: Fix from earlier: `input_string[-x-1]`. With those indices it now works

Comment: Does someone want me to post an answer or is that okay?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the variabile "reverse_string" will always be equal to "input_string" since you are just appending the characters in the same order with the += operator.

A simple way to reverse a string in Python is to use slicing like that:

```
def is_palindrome(input_string):    
    if input_string == input_string[::-1]:
        return True
    return False
```

`input_string[::-1]` means "start from the first index to the last in the reverse order (-1)"

Comment: you should just return the comparison and not use a conditional and two return statements

Comment: Well, that's just for illustrating how it works. In a real world scenario you probably not even define a function since it's a single instruction...

Comment: I disagree. Having a function called `is_palindrome` can be very useful, even though it can be implemented in a single line. If you have a class `Word` you might want a method to check if it's palindrome, so you will need a function for that.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the reversal of the string. (your x is going from 0 to len(input_string)-1 but it should go the other way)

That's why it's important to break code into functions that do one and only one thing (at least in the beginning)

In this case is an overkill, but it will help you when your code grows more complex.

your function can then be simplified as:

```
def is_palindrome(input_string): 
    return input_string == reverse_string(input_string)
```

If you look at it is self explanatory. Is the input string equal to its reverse?

Now we need to implement the function `reverse_string`.

The advantage of having a function that just reverses a string is that we can do a lot of tests on it to check just this particular function

In your case, you can use negative indexes, or you can start with the index set to len(input_string)-1 and go towards 0.

But it's also a good moment to learn about string slicing and how to do things in a pythonic way, so the reverse function can be written as:

```
def reverse_string(input_string):
    return input_string[::-1]
```

Feel free to put your own implementation of reverse_string if you are not yet confident with string slicing, but with this function you have separated two different things: reversing a string and checking is  string is a palindrome. You can even reuse that reverse_string function later on.

Now we can test it with many cases until we are confident that it works as expected.

I'd recommend taking a look at [unit tests](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html)  it might seem too much for such an easy problem, but it will help you a lot in the future.

Just test what happens if you pass a palindrome, a non-palindrome, an empty string, a number, a `None`...